# Only getting JSON decode error when implemented in a class

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a local JSON file as a pseudo database and I am writing a connection class to interact with it.  I am getting a JSON decode error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

when trying to read in the file to a variable

I have the below class in db.py:

```
import json

class DBconnect:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.dbfile = open(filename, 'r+')

    def __read(self):
        return json.load(self.dbfile) # line that stacktrace lands on
```

the data in the json file:

```
{"key": {"1": {}}, "keyTwo": {"1": {}}}
```

I also created a test program that reads a json file with no class and I did not get an error. It produces a Python dict just as intended.

Is it the implementation within a class that is causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. `print(handle.dbfile.read())` prints the contents when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was happening. I was calling __read() in another function before the error occurs so the file position was at the end of the file. I added:

```
self.dbfile.seek(0)
```

before the return statement and it fixed the problem